# Can't get basic shapes to show up when using SpriteWidget framework for Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sprite

I'm trying to get just a circle to show up using the SpriteWidget framework for Flutter but I get nothing but a black screen.

```
class SpriteWidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SpriteWidgetTestState createState() => SpriteWidgetTestState();
}

class SpriteWidgetTestState extends State<SpriteWidgetTest> {
  var rootNode = NodeWithSize(const Size(1024.0, 2048.0));

  @override
  void initState() {
    var circ = CircleNode(radius: 50, color: Colors.yellow);
    rootNode.addChild(circ);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SpriteWidget(rootNode);
}

class CircleNode extends Node {
  @required
  double radius;
  Color color = Colors.black;
  CircleNode({this.radius, this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset.zero,
      radius,
      Paint()..color = color,
    );
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to follow along with the README in the SpriteWidget repo but not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: new and inexperienced in both answering questions and Flutter, but I was having this problem and I have (kind of) figured it out.

You *are* rendering the circle, but it's out of view. You can see this in action by making the radius of the circle ridiculously huge (1000+). You should have a large yellow blob engulf your screen.

This seems to be because SpriteWidget renders the node a thousand miles to the top left. You can centre it by setting the root node's position to half the node's size.

```
rootNode = new NodeWithSize(const Size(1024.0, 1024.0));
rootNode.position = Offset(512, 512);
```

I'm fairly sure this is just a workaround and there's a proper way to solve this, but I hope it helps.